# Placeholder for an input field working as a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a placeholder for an input field that is a drop down list. But somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: At this point, your question is a bit broad. Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: show your example code .

Comment: There is no place holder for select option but you can use first <option> for showing your massage

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example on how to define a placeholder for a drop down list:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Something</option>
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
</select>
```